# Copy new and changed files by LastModifiedDate with Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Using the copy activity, I need to fetch only the latest file within a folder.

Example:
Folder

File1

File2
where File2 is the latest one.

However, it is taking both files.

I followed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-copy-new-files-lastmodifieddate

Also tried in the source dataset>Connection>Filter by last modified

> Start Date: @adddays(utcnow(),-31)
>
> End Date: utcnow()

I expect only the last modified file to be taken within the range date specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rough idea is using such flow:Get Metadata activity-->Azure Function Activity-->Copy Activity.

Step1:using [Metadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#metadata-options) to get the last modified datetime of the files in the specific folder within the range date specified.

Step2:pass the output array to [azure function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity),use bubble sort(or other compare algorithm) to get the latest modified file name and filter others.Output that file name.

Step3:pass the file name to copy activity to do the transmission.

You could get some similar clues from this case:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/affdcb44-6a8c-4b20-8e2e-6da20ab86c32/default-sorting-of-get-metadata-activity?forum=AzureDataFactory

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the OP did not press the "Publish" button after making changes to the "Filter by last modified" fields (i.e. Start Time and End Time). The trigger only will act upon the state of the ADF as it sits in your Publish branch. So even if you hit the Save or Save All button which saves changes to the Collaboration branch, that isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach for a similar problem. I noticed that getmetadata activity returns the file names in ascending order. so in the child items array file1 will come first, followed by file2, file3 etc.

I used the following steps.

1. get child items using a getmetadata activity
2. define a sting variable v_filename
3. iterate child items through foreach loop in sequential mode
4. inside the foreach loop use a setvariable activity which will overwrite the v_filename in each iteration
5. After the final iteration the variable will have the latest file name
6. use your copy activty after the foreach and pass v_filename as filename.

it works